# python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty dataframe:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame()
```

I would like to append more temporary dataframes to this empty dataframe:

```
for data in list:
    df_temporary_data = method_which_provides_df_with_data()
    pd.concat([df_data, df_temporary_data])
```

The temporary dataframes have the same structure, but after the concatenation the program ends up with the following result:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Could you please provide a solution for this problem? (With append method, the result is still an empty dataframe.)

In the end, I would like to get a final dataframe with the data of the temporary dataframes (which have similar columns).

Comment: `pd.concat` returns the concatenation of its arguments. In your code you are ignoring the return value. Try `df_data = pd.concat(etc...)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried it another way which is worked. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The question was not the best, my bad...

I created a df_list, which contains the temporary df-s and used the pd.concat method:

```
df_list = []
    for data in list:
        df_temporary_data = method_which_provides_df_with_data()
        df_list.append(df_temporary_data)
    pd.concat(df_list)
```